# RabbitTemplate async message with callback

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm struggling with async RabbitMQ message with callback message.

Here is part of my producer:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("rabbitTemplate")
private RabbitTemplate queueTemplate;

@Override
public Response createIncident(String incident) {
    LOGGER.info("Sending incident into queue");
    queueTemplate.convertAndSend((Object)incident, new MessagePostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
            message.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo("replyQueue");
            return message;
        }
    });
    Message message = queueTemplate.receive();
...
```

Spring rabbitMQ context

```
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="rabbitQueue" />
<rabbit:queue name="replyQueue" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="rabbitExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="rabbitQueue" pattern="camel" />
        <rabbit:binding queue="replyQueue" pattern="camel" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>


<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" 
    connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" exchange="rabbitExchange" routing-key="camel"
    reply-address="replyQueue" reply-queue="replyQueue">
    <rabbit:reply-listener/>
</rabbit:template>

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" concurrency="10">
    <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitMessageListener" method="createIncident"
        queue-names="rabbitQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="rabbitMessageListener" class="com.my.listener.QueueListener" />
```

And Listener that should receive and respond

```
@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("rabbitTemplate")
private RabbitTemplate queueTemplate;

public void createIncident() {
    queueTemplate.receiveAndReply("replyQueue", new ReceiveAndReplyMessageCallback() {

        @Override
        public Message handle(Message message) {
            String incident = new String(message.getBody());
            LOGGER.debug("Queue incoming message: " + incident);
            String result = "" + messageHandler.createIncident(incident);
            return new Message(result.getBytes(), new MessageProperties());
        }

    });
```

It do not want to get inside this handle message in listener. And application container display message

> 2016-06-22 14:15:30,457 ERROR
>   [AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver:115] Error occurred during error
>   handling, give up! org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No 'queue'
>   specified. Check configuration of RabbitTemplate.     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.mobilitymedia.connected.http.core.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: No 'queue'
>   specified. Check configuration of RabbitTemplate.     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.getRequiredQueue(RabbitTemplate.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.receive(RabbitTemplate.java:802)
>     at
>   com.myService.IncidentServiceDefaultImpl.createIncident(IncidentServiceDefaultImpl.java:36)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
>     ... 65 more

Comment: Post full stacktrace.

Comment: I am having same problem, did you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
/**
 * The name of the default queue to receive messages from when none is specified explicitly.
 *
 * @param queue the default queue name to use for receive
 */
public void setQueue(String queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}
```

instead of `reply-address`.

And reconsider your

```
queueTemplate.receiveAndReply("replyQueue",
```

Seems for me listener should take a look into some different queue bound to the `routing-key="camel"`.

Although you still have a mess with `<binding>` as well.

Plus it would be better to take a look if your really can use `ListenerContainer` on the consumer part instead of `receiveAndReply`.